# StarTeam Report: How to add the Change Request # of a file's last check-in?

Tags: starteam

I'm trying to create a report in StarTeam. I need it to list the file name, time of the last check-in and the Change Request linked to the file's last check-in. (We tie every check-in to a Change Request). So far I've been able to take one of the built-in reports and modify it to show me the file name and time of last check-in. However, I can't figure out how to get the Change Request number.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already using the StarTeam SDK for creating that report,
you should catch the **link** between the **file-revision** and the **CR** (or CR-revision).

To explain:

When checking-in a file, the developer selects the CR that the fix was done for.
This operation attaches that revision of the file to a revision of the CR selected.

In your report -

1. find the revision of the file (usually, you want the latest one)
2. find any links attached to that file-revision (usually - one)
3. find the CR that is attached to that link, if any